# option button value copy to the master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks have worksheet sheets1 each having  2option button

〇aa
〇bb

and I want to copy the select Option button caption to the MasterWork
also, for example, if I select the 〇aa option my task will copy aa as option text to the destination range for all workbooks.

I have tried this code on the window form how can I do it if the Options button is present in sheet1 of multiple workbooks?

```vb
varOpt1= UserForm1.Opt1.Value
varOpt2= UserForm1.Opt2.Value

If varOpt1 = True Then
   ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Value = UserForm1.Opt1.Caption
ElseIf varOpt2= True Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Value = UserForm1.Opt2.Caption
Else
        
End If
```

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're having with your code to do this?  What is preventing you from achieving your goal?

Comment: To make a date from 3 separate year, month and day values you can use `DateSerial(y, m, d)`

Comment: I have multiple xlsx file(which are not opened).  
I want to copy the selected range value of each Workbook to the single row of the new workbook
if the options button is checked copy the options button caption value to the destination cell.